# Can somebody tell me why block doesn't wait for objc handler?

Tags: ios, iphone, grand-central-dispatch

Again, question about GCD. I don't know why they were invented as they don't work properly or I misunderstood something.

I've got some `controller` for adding new Coupon. It is responsible to saving details into Core Data. Then ImagesCollection is used to pick up some imgs and used to convert `UIImage` into `NSData`.

It looks something like that:

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonClicked:(id)sender {
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
__block NSSet *imgs = nil;

if (!imagesCollection) 
    imgs = [self.coupon couponImages];

[imagesCollection saveImagesWithCompletion:^(NSSet *images, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:error.localizedDescription
                                    message:error.localizedFailureReason
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    } else {
        imgs = [images copy];
    }
}];

------- PhotosCollection --------
@interface...
typedef void (^ImagesCompletionBlock)(NSSet *images, NSError *error);
-(void)saveImagesWithCompletion:(ImagesCompletionBlock)completion;

@implementation...
ImagesCompletionBlock _block;

-(void)saveImagesWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSSet *images, NSError *error))success {
_block = [success copy];
NSError *error = nil;


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    NSMutableSet *processedImages = [NSMutableSet new];

    for (UIImage *image in images) {
        [processedImages addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)]];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (_block) {
            _block([processedImages copy],error);
        }
    });
});
}
```

How it doesn't wait for completion handler to be fired??

Thanks for any help,
Frustrated - Adrian.

Comment: What doesn't wait for the completion handler to be fired?

Comment: Controller doesn't wait for images and/or error.

Comment: I still don't understand. Where do you expect the code to "wait?"

Comment: saveImagesWithCompletion should wait for data to come from PhotosCollection

Comment: Why would it?  You are dispatching the block with the for loop asynchronously. Once this block is dispatched it will execute on the background queue at some point in the near future and `saveImagesWithCompletion`  will return. Once the for loop has finished it will execute the completion block on the main queue.  This is the whole point of asynchronous dispatch - to allow long running or intensive tasks to execute without blocking the main thread (which impacts UI responsiveness)

Comment: The whole point of asynchronous calls is that saveImagesWithCompletion does _not_ wait for data to come. Synchronous = wait, Asynchronous = don't wait.

Comment: Okay, I actually see the point now. Thanks for this explanation. Is it possible to actually, wait for asynchronous call and then add new Coupon with fetched Images from ImagesCollection?